# Does Lightning for gmail work with inbox?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, gmail

I configured Lightning for Gmail, I was able t get it working from mial.google.com however when I swtich to inbox.google.com I no longer see the Salesforce side panel. Is there a solution for this?